# How to combine sliding menu and uitabbarcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, slidingmenu, swrevealviewcontroller

I am trying to integrate `UITabBarController` with Sliding menu. I'm using `SWRevealViewController` to create the sliding menu.

Following is the picture of my story board.

[image]

But the `TabView` is visible only for news. I want it to be like a new view just as android. In android we can combine both Navigation Drawer and `TabPager`.
How can I do so in iOS?

Comment: Check this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932069/unable-to-use-uitabbarcontroller-with-sliding-side-menu/36932163#36932163

Comment: Yes...i tried it but it did not work. Can you please provide a sample project?

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows :

```
MainTabViewController *frontViewController = [[MainTabViewController alloc] init];
RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearViewController];

SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];
revealController.delegate = self;

self.viewController = revealController;
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```